# Replace Javascript is not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replace more than 1 word in same string, with RegExp, but it seems is not working, i tryied some answers here in stackoverflow, but with no result

```js
var _tpl = "time working $times, not now $times"
var reg = "$times"
var regexp = new RegExp(reg, "g")
var replaceFor = 1


var _newTpl = _tpl.replace(regexp, replaceFor)

console.log(_newTpl)
```

some advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` is a special character in a regular expression: you must escape it.

```js
var _tpl = "time working $times, not now $times"
var reg = "\\$times"
var regexp = new RegExp(reg, "g")
var replaceFor = 1


var _newTpl = _tpl.replace(regexp, replaceFor)

console.log(_newTpl)
```

Note that you need two `\`s in order to put a single literal `\` in the resulting string. If you create the regular expression directly, with regex syntax and not string syntax, only use one `\`:

```
const regexp = /\$times/g;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape regex' special characters before passing them to `new RegExp`.

```
var reg = "\\$times"
```

```js
var _tpl = "time working $times, not now $times"
var reg = "\\$times"
var regexp = new RegExp(reg,"g")
var replaceFor = 1
var _newTpl = _tpl.replace(regexp, replaceFor)

console.log(_newTpl)
```